# Bootstrap table "item per page" dropdownlist not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap table for present my data.

Everything works, but there is dropdown to select number of items per page

[image]

There is my code. **Do you have any idea, maybe there is some issues with versions?**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.0/locale/bootstrap-table-en-US.min.js"></script>
...
<table id="goalsListTable"
       class="table table-striped"
       data-toggle="table" data-url="@Url.Content("~/Goal/GoalListJson")" 
       data-side-pagination="server"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50]"
       data-page-size="25">
    <thead> ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap table you can use page pageSize property like:

```
<script>
    $('#goalsListTable').bootstrapTable({
        pagination: true,
        pageSize: 25, //your page size here
        pageList: [25, 50, 75, 100]//list of page sizes
    });
</script>
```

And here a basic codepen example of this script overwriting the `data-page-list` and `data-page-size` values:

http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/qRrEap

Or another example from their documentation is to use the `data-query-params` value:

```
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-url="https://api.github.com/users/wenzhixin/repos"
       data-query-params="queryParams"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-height="300">
</table>
```

And then declare `queryParams` the way you want it:

```
function queryParams() {
    return {
        type: 'owner',
        sort: 'updated',
        direction: 'desc',
        per_page: 25,
        page: 1
    };
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/42/

***UPDATE***

The code you pasted was missing the bootstrap JavaScript link.  That is required for the dropdowns to work correctly.  Include that link in your code like so:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The codepen has been updated with a working example.

Comment: I saw page with that example, but problem is with "data-page-list", which drive displaying items' count  per page. So I think :/

Comment: `data-page-list` should be overwritten by this new value you are assigning to `pageList` in my answer.  You may have to put that script below the table so it will run after it is initialized.  I updated my answer with a codepen showing it working.

Comment: Problem which I describe appears in your example on jsfiddle.
Try to scroll down, and click on dropdown. It should expands with values [25, 50, 75, 100] from data-page-list

Comment: @Jacek I found the issue.  Your code is not including bootstraps JavaScript file which the dropdown relies on.  The codepen link in my answer has been updated.

Comment: Now everything works correct. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Weird, I have the same problem, but my JS IS include in the page. Dropdown still doesn't work.